# I can directly access std::array's data, is this a defect?

Tags: c++, c++11

One of the consequences of `std::array` is that its implementation-defined data must be public or else it will no longer be an aggregate. This allows me to do stuff like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 5> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    #if defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION)
        for (int i : arr.__elems_)
    #else
        for (int i : arr._M_elems)
    #endif
        std::cout << i;
}
```

This seems rather wonky to me, considering that most of the standard library is well encapsulated and protected from misuse. Is there any workaround to this? Could the interface of `std::array` be improved?

Answer (score 6):

The standard committee did fine by making your code illegal. You are using implementation reserved identifiers. If you are going to shoot yourself in the foot intentionally, then that is not the committee's problem.

In this special case the "misuse" does not even matter because you can access that data via the "official" interface anyways. But even if that was not the case, again: Just don't do stupid stuff on purpose.

Comment: There is no rule stating that I can't *use* an identifier with a reserved name, just that declaring or defining one results in undefined behavior. Furthermore, "undefined behavior" does not mean "illegal", in standardese or not.

Comment: @user5438884 The precise wording in the Standard regarding those identifiers is '[…] shall not be used otherwise; no diagnostic required' (2.10/3 [lex.name]). In other words, you’re as much allowed to use those identifiers as you are allowed to run code dereferencing a null pointer or dividing by zero.

Comment: @user5438884  *""undefined behavior" does not mean "illegal""* How do you define illegal then?